# Adding new methods to Object prototype in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

How do I add a new method to the Object prototype in Ruby, such that the method receives the object passed to it, and can manipulate it.

So I can take a derivative of the Object prototype such as Fixnum and do the following

1.my_new_method

which will manipulate the 1 object and return something new

Comment: What's wrong with adding an instance or a class method? Am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just open existing class and define a method

```
class Fixnum
  def my_method
    puts "Hello! I am #{self}"
  end

  def squared
    self**2
  end
end

2.my_method        #=> 'Hello! I am 2' 
3.squared          #=> 9
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using FixNum as an example, I should be opening the object class

Answer (score 0):

You just open the Object class and define a method

```
class Object
  def my_method
    puts "Hello! I am #{self}"
  end

  def double
    self+self
  end
end

2.my_method        #=> 'Hello! I am 2' 
3.double           #=> 9
"a".double         #=> "aa"
```